# How to interpolate a 5 dimensional array?

Tags: numpy, interpolation, data-analysis

I have an array of shape- [41, 101, 6, 4, 280]. I want to interpolate it so that if I give it a value from 41 temperature and 101 density values, it spits out an array of [6,4,280] shape. Is there a NumPy function that can deal with this?

Comment: "a value from 41 temperature and 101 density values" what exactly do you mean by this? You mean two real values between 0 and 41 and 0 and 101? Or two real values picked from two arrays of 41 and 101 elements (where each value is associated with the corresponding position in the 5D array)? Or two arbitrary real values in the range covered by two such arrays (and interpolate accordingly)?

Answer (score 1):

let's start step by step :

> **Q** : *Is there a **NumPy function** that can deal with this?*

Yes, there is.

The first step is to generate an instance of a 5D **`numpy.ndarray`**, that will contain your known data-points ( do not mind the `dtype`, that was used for just reminding we can go literally from bits upto **`complex128`** values here, if later needed ):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>>
>>> a5Dtensor = np.ndarray( (41, 101, 6, 4, 280 ), dtype = np.uint8 )
```

Now, let's validate it's `.shape` :

```
>>> a5Dtensor.shape
(41, 101, 6, 4, 280)
```

The core trick is the built-in smart `numpy`-slicing :

```
>>> a5Dtensor[0,0,:,:,:].shape
(6, 4, 280)
```

This indeed returns the requested 3D-cube of data-points.
The slicing-trick is also very smart in not producing any new memory-allocations (which will be of interest once the sizes grow somewhere beyond L1/L2/L3-CPU-cache horizons, the more once you get beyond a few GB-of data)

```
>>> a5Dtensor[0,0,:,:,:].flags
  C_CONTIGUOUS    : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS    : False <------ may enjoy FORTRAN efficient data layout, where needed
  OWNDATA         : False <------ 3D-cube data not "copied", rather "viewed" inside 5D
  WRITEABLE       : True
  ALIGNED         : True
  WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False
  UPDATEIFCOPY    : False
```

Last, but not least, if **`aTemperatureVALUE`** and **`aDensityVALUE`** variables are not indices into 5D, but rather data-values, among which you seek for the sought for interpolation of 3D-cube datapoints' values, the `numpy` can serve with a piecewise linear interpolation ( with some constraints ), yet making any such interpolation for each of the result ( in the 3D-cube of interpolated-values ) requires a 2D-interpolation being run for each of the 3D-cube coordinates, based on the values held for nearest-`{ lower, upper }` temperature and density values, present in the original 5D-data-points.

There are other smart tools for this in `numpy` ( nD; n = 0+ `.meshgrid()` method, `.argwhere()` and others ), yet finding ( pre-sorting ), indirect indexing may be needed for this, in case the original 5D-data-points do not exhibit some properties, like a 3D-cubes of data-point having been already pre-sorted in the first two dimensions for easier processing for the sought-for 2D-*(temp,density)*-interpolator ( be it specifically tailor-made for `dtype=uint8`, `float64`, `complex128` or `object` ).